# Technical analysis of von Neumann's contributions to computing?

Tags: computer-science, von-neumann

I have seen the book *The Annotated Turing* and I found it quite nice to understand the ideas of Alan Turing. Are there similar books for understanding von Neumann's ideas in computing?

Comment: [Aspray, John Von Neumann and the Origins of Modern Computing](https://www.google.com/books/edition/John_von_Neumann_and_the_Origins_of_Mode/srhNEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0)